# Skip un-set meta fields ("Invalid field: fieldname") when using `wp post list` and displaying custom fields

Tags: custom-field, wp-cli

We have custom fields called `country`
and `coordinator`.

This works:

```
$ wp post list \
  --post__in=81153 \
  --post_type=boardmember \
  --fields=ID,post_title,post_name,post_date,post_status,country,coordinator \
  --meta_key=country --meta_key=coordinator
+-------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------+-------------+---------+-------------+
| ID    | post_title                  | post_name                   | post_date           | post_status | country | coordinator |
+-------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------+-------------+---------+-------------+
| 81153 | A Person | a-person | 2023-10-09 11:47:35 | publish     | Mexico  | 0           |
+-------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------+-------------+---------+-------------+
```

However, trying to list all posts with both fields fails:

```
$ wp post list \
  --post__in=81153 \
  --post_type=boardmember \
  --fields=ID,post_title,post_name,post_date,post_status,country,coordinator \
  --meta_key=country --meta_key=coordinator
Error: Invalid field: country.
```

Interestingly, it does seem to work fine with just one of the fields:

```
$ wp post list \
  --post_type=boardmember \
  --fields=ID,post_title,post_name,post_date,post_status,country \
  --meta_key=country
# works
$ wp post list \
  --post_type=boardmember \
  --fields=ID,post_title,post_name,post_date,post_status,coordinator \
  --meta_key=coordinator
# also works
```

Does anyone know of a way to skip posts with a missing custom field, while loading multiple custom fields?

Comment: Maybe --meta_compare=EXISTS ?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @birgire! Your comment helped me realise the problem is actually a little different than I thought, updated my question. But unfortunately adding `--meta-compare=EXISTS` doesn't seem to help, whether I add one, two or 3 instances of it.

Comment: What wp-cli version? you might add your opinion under discussions on possible --meta_query support: https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/5585. You can also create a custom wp-cli command for your needs or even run custom PHP with wp eval or wp eval-file.